# Automatically refresh window when login

Tags: php, facebook, browser, authentication, refresh

I have a facebook app that might run in a tab. If the user is not logged in, it displays a login button. I would want the window to automatically refresh if the user logs in from another window/ tab. Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a function in javascript that checks if the user is logged in and refreshes the page if so.
Lets say I call this function `checkIfUserIsLoggedIn()`, then I would put that function in an interval with `setInterval("checkIfUserIsLoggedIn()", intervalTime);`
So this way you can for example let the page check every 10 seconds if the user was logged in and have it refresh if so.

Comment: Lol meanwhile I looked a bit on fb js sdk and they have a getLoginStatus function. Just have to set interval and refresh the window. Thanks